# Can I call posix_fadvise when another thread is reading/writing the fd?

Tags: c++, linux

I'm working a project under linux, which needs read/write the same fd using multi-threads. And I want to use `posix_fadvise` to free page cache.

Can I call `posix_fadvise` when another thread is reading or writing the same fd?

Answer (score 1):

Read [posix_fadvise(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/posix_fadvise.2.html) and [syscalls(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html). Since `posix_fadvise` is a genuine [syscall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syscall) (e.g. wraps `fadvise64` having its `__NR_fadvise64` in `<asm/unistd.h>`...) you should be able to call it while another thread is writing the same fd, exactly as you may have two threads doing [write(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/write.2.html) to the same file descriptor (but what happens then is perhaps non-deterministic).

<sup>I imagine that the kernel is internally locking the kernel file object referenced by a file descriptor.</sup>

BTW, the man page of `posix_advise` tells:

> ```
>   Programs can use posix_fadvise() to announce an intention to access
>   file data in a specific pattern in the future, thus allowing the
>   kernel to perform appropriate optimizations.
> ```

```
   The advice applies to a (not necessarily existent) region starting at
   offset and extending for len bytes (or until the end of the file if
   len is 0) within the file referred to by fd.  The advice is not
   binding; it merely constitutes an expectation on behalf of the
   application.
```

Hence I *guess* that the kernel *may* follow the `posix_fadvise` later (or not at all)...

So I think you can do that, but I believe you should avoid, at least for readability reasons (and because of the non-determinism), to have several threads working on the same file descriptor. My feeling is that your code may have some *design issues*, but something will perhaps happen...

Generally, I would avoid having several threads doing I/O on the same file descriptor (or at the very least, use [pwrite(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/pwrite.2.html) or lock the I/O with a mutex...). So while you could do what you are asking, I would avoid doing that.

Remember that I/O operations to a disk file system are much much slower (they may take many milliseconds) that ordinary computations. Locking them with a mutex should not be significant, and will give you more determinism.

Comment: Thanks for your advise. When using SSD, i think multi-thread will help to improve performance. As you mentioned above, we use pwrite/pread API to manipulate file.